# Find a value of an input element with DOM using a jquery loop

Tags: jquery

I have divs with the class 'well'. I loop all the divs to get the unique numbers and put them to an array in jquery. And that works.

But there is also an input object and I will get the value in the same loop. I will find the value on dom element. Does anybody know how to do that?

```
<div class="well" id=media$[unique number]>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="mediabank-input">
    <input id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control" type="text” />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
var mediaIdsArray = [];
$('#media-grid .well').each(function (index) {  
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var split_id = id.split("&");
 mediaIdsArray.push(split_id[1]);
});
```

Comment: This part is not clear "But there is also an input object and I will get the value in the same loop. I will find the value on dom element. Does anybody know how to do that?"

can reword your question please?

Comment: @CuriousBenjamin I think it's a poor translation of "I *want to* get the value in the same loop"

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you need to traverse the DOM from the `.well` element in the loop to find its child `input`. As you're using jQuery this can be done using `find()`.

Also note that you need to use `$` in the `split()` call, not `&`. In addition you can use `map()` to build the array much more simply. Finally, be careful of repeating the same `#caption` id if the HTML in the example is repeated, as `id` must be unique. Change this to a class instead.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var mediaIdsArray = $('#media-grid .well').map((i, el) => ({
  id: el.id.split('$')[1],
  value: $(el).find('input.caption').val()
})).get();

console.log(mediaIdsArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="media-grid">
  <div class="well" id="media$1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mediabank-input">
          <input name="caption" class="caption form-control" type="text" value="foo" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well" id="media$2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mediabank-input">
          <input name="caption" class="caption form-control" type="text" value="bar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well" id="media$3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mediabank-input">
          <input name="caption" class="caption form-control" type="text" value="fizz" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the reference to `this` you can traverse the DOM (with methods like `.find()` for example) to get a reference to the `<input>` within that node.  For example:

```
var value = $(this).find('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find()` method to get the input element placed inside your main div.

```
var mediaIdsArray = [];

$('#media-grid .well').each(function (index, ele) {  

   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var split_id = id.split("&");
   mediaIdsArray.push(split_id[1]);

   let inputVal = $(ele).find('#captions').val()
});
```